# загрузка картинки со смартфона в webwiew

Tags: android, webview

Добрый день! Помогите справиться с проблемой:
Есть проект с webView, через него открывается сайт и на сайте есть кнопка "загрузить фото". При нажатии по ней в webView открывается окошко с выбором камеры или галереи.

Для справки. **Этот код рабочий для версий от 6.0.1 до 4.4.4.**

Так вот, на версии андроид 4.2.2 не пашет. **Что можно сделать, чтоб работали версии ниже KitKat?** Грешу на `onActivityResult`

Для проверки уже внесён сайт. На сайте перейти на - "подать объявление" - "добавить фотографии"

Ниже приведён мой код(Облазил интернет и собрал в кучку методы, не все методы понимаю, шёл по ответам и проверял методом тыка)

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView mWebView;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

//new block
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
public static final String EXTRA_FROM_NOTIFICATION = "EXTRA_FROM_NOTIFICATION";
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
private String mCameraPhotoPath;

// Storage Permissions
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        // Marshmallow+
        verifyStoragePermissions(MainActivity.this);

    } /*else {
        // Pre-Marshmallow
    }*/

    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    setUpWebViewDefaults(mWebView);

    if(!IsConnectingToInternet.check()){
        FragmentAlert dlg = FragmentAlert.newInstance();
        dlg.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "fragment1");
    }else {
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (progress == 100) {
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }


            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

                //verifyStoragePermissions(MainActivity.this);
                Log.e("111","onShowFileChooser");
                if(mFilePathCallback != null) {
                    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                    }

                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

                Intent[] intentArray;
                if(takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

                return true;
            }

            // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                System.out.println("in 3.0+");
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                File imageStorageDir = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                        , "AndroidExampleFolder");
                if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                    // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                    imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                }
                // Create camera captured image file path and name
                File file = new File(
                        imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                                + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                + ".jpg");
                mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);


                //

                // Camera capture image intent
                final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                // Create file chooser intent
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
                // Set camera intent to file chooser
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                        , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });
                // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity






                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }
            // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                System.out.println("in <3.0");
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
            }

            // openFileChooser for other Android versions
            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                        String acceptType, String capture) {
                System.out.println("in OTHER");
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);

            }
        });
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://dagbarter.ru");
    }

}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    return imageFile;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setUpWebViewDefaults(WebView webView) {
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

    // Enable Javascript
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Use WideViewport and Zoom out if there is no viewport defined
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    // Enable pinch to zoom without the zoom buttons
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // Hide the zoom controls for HONEYCOMB+
        settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    }

    // Enable remote debugging via chrome://inspect
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }

    // We set the WebViewClient to ensure links are consumed by the WebView rather
    // than passed to a browser if it can
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}


private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
Uri KitkatPath ;

@Override
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        Uri[] results = null;

        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
        }

        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        System.out.println("In KitKat Condition");

        if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
            System.out.println("In != Null");
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

            System.out.println("requestCode == FileChooser ResultCode");
            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                System.out.println("In null == this.mUploadMessage");
                return;
            }
            Uri result = null;
            try {
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                    result = null;
                } else {

                    //newcode

                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();

                    KitkatPath = Uri.parse("file://"+getPath(MainActivity.this, result));
                    System.out.println("KitkatPath== "+KitkatPath);
                    System.out.println("result = "+result);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(KitkatPath);
            System.out.println("mUploadMessage = "+mUploadMessage);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }

}

/** CODE FOR FILE UPLOAD*/



public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}


/////////////////////
/**
 * Checks if the app has permission to write to device storage
 *
 * If the app does not has permission then the user will be prompted to grant permissions
 *
 * @param activity
 */
public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {

    int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_Camera=101;

    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int permissionCheck = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    } else  if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_Camera
        );
    }
}
}
```

Файл манифеста

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name=".ApplicationContext"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: а запостите пожалуйста, как вы объявляете activity в манифесте. интересует именно launchMode. так же поясните, в чем именно проблема? что именно не работает?

Comment: и еще. исходники это, конечно, хорошо. но уважайте чужое время - не удаляйте участки кода, которые точно не относятся к проблеме.

Comment: @babay, не понял последний комментарий

Comment: упс. опечатка. имел ввиду, удаляйте участки кода, которые точно не имеют отношения к проблеме.

Comment: @babay, самое интересное, проект состоит из 1 класса, в котором 1 только webView и progressBar) даже не знаю, как этот код уменьшить, все методы в нём ориентированы на webView

Comment: @babay, Обновил вопрос, дополнив файл манифеста. Проблема именно в отображении диалогового окна(загрузить фото с камеры или с галереи) на версиях от 4.0 до 4.3, окно просто не появляется. На 6-х, 5-х и 4.4.4 появляется. Вы можете увидеть окно, о котором я говорю, перейдя в браузере телефона по [ссылке]  и нажать "добавить фотографии" (http://www.dagbarter.ru/announcement/update/287581) или  `www.dagbarter.ru` -> подать объявление -> добавить фотографии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

исследование показало, что всё работает с приведенной на stackoverflow страницей:
http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/199/index.html

и не работает с вашей страницей.

попробуйте перейти к форме, использующей `<input type="file" />`. полагаю, это решит вашу проблему.

Comment: Вы правы. Видимо, это от страниц зависит

Comment: @zayn1991 зависит от того, как именно отправляется файл на сервер. с использованием `<input type="file" />` - более старый способ. потому с ним и работает.

Comment: вот сейчас я в недоумении. Форма, использующая <input type="file" /> - Вы про форму страницы сайта говорите, либо это свойство прописывается в проекте андроид студии?

Comment: @zayn1991 про форму на странице сайта. дело именно в ней. в той форме на странице сайта, которая используется для отправки файла.

Comment: по Вашей ссылке проект грузит "null" файлы с приложения. Это уже, наверное нужно как то создавать методы загрузки под версии 4.0-4.3?
Только пол проблемы решено(

Answer (score 1):

С версии Android 4.4 (API level 19) WebView теперь основано на базе Chromium.
https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html
Возможно в этом и проблема. Есть библиотеки которые позволяют использовать "навороченное" WebView на версиях ниже 4.4, например Crosswalk Project https://habrahabr.ru/post/263649/
но у него есть ряд минусов, один из них это размер апк примерно в 60-80 мб.

Comment: прога раз в 10 тяжелее станет, как то не греет меня эта информация), но на крайний случай можно подключить